# How to fix this bug ? Unexpected SyntaxError: Unexpected token '!'

Tags: reactjs, firebase, error-handling, syntax-error, unexpected-token

So basically the console is showing me that I have an unexpected token but I don't think there is any unexpected token. Please help me. I have taken way too much time trying to fix this problem. Here is the code -

```
import React from 'react';
import firebase from 'firebase';

export default function App() {
  // I have deleted this information because I don't want anyone to access my data
  const firebaseConfig = {};

  firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

  function signInWithGoogle() {
    var google_provider = new firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider();
    firebase
      .auth()
      .signInWithPopup(google_provider)
      .then((res) => {
        console.log(res);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
      });
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Google Sign In Authentication</h1>
      <button onClick={signInWithGoogle}>Sign In</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Please provide more of the console error message you are getting. 
Also, you might not want to expose the firebaseConfig-data to everyone.

Comment: Unexpected SyntaxError: Unexpected token '!'. Only this is shown in the console

Comment: I got the issue i had to use "firebase/compat/app". thank you for helping me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only issue I see in the provided code is you have not imported the Firebase Auth SDK. You can import that as shown below:

```
import firebase from 'firebase';
import "firebase/auth"
```

Also make sure you are using `V8.X.X` or lower with above code. If you have new Modular SDK `V9.0.0+` then change your imports to compat version to keep using existing code:

```
import firebase from 'firebase/compat/app';
import "firebase/compat/auth"
```

Comment: Thank you so much, brother!! You are amazing!! You don't know how many hours this took me and you have come to my rescue! God Bless You. Hope you get an amazing coding job and keep up the good work